# mcrypt_encrypt(): Mcrypt initialisation failed

Tags: php, laravel-5, mcrypt, password-encryption

I downloaded example Laravel 5 project and try to test on my local machine. But
I can see errors like following:

**ErrorException in User.php line 115:**
**mcrypt_encrypt(): Mcrypt initialisation failed**

```
1. in User.php line 115
2. at HandleExceptions->handleError('4096', 'mcrypt_encrypt(): Mcrypt     initialisation failed', 'C:\wamp\www\noj\app\Models\User.php', '115',     array('pure_string' => 'asdfasdf', 'USER_PASSWORD_SALT' => null, 'key' => '', 'iv_size' => '8', 'iv' => 'ЎZo\S '))
3. at mcrypt_encrypt('blowfish', '', 'asdfasdf', 'ecb', 'ЎZo\S ') in User.php line 115
4. at User::encrypthash('asdfasdf') in Registrar.php line 36
5. at Registrar->create(array('_token' => '7oIiiOAtUu4Quc949u7SmtcDlI5a0zo0AEJgBA3S', 'name' => 'Bob', 'email' => 'bob@example.com', 'password' => 'asdfasdf', 'password_confirmation' => 'asdfasdf')) in AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php line 50
6. at AuthController->postRegister(object(Request))</li>
...
```

### User.php

```
        ...  
108.    public static function encrypthash($pure_string) {
109.        //xulianwhocreatenoj
110.        $USER_PASSWORD_SALT = env('USER_PASSWORD_SALT');
111.        $key = pack('H*', $USER_PASSWORD_SALT);
112.        $pure_string = trim($pure_string);
113.        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
114.        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
115.        $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
116.        return base64_encode($encrypted_string);
117.    }
        ...
```

I do not have deep knowledge about PHP nor mcrypt_encrypt() function.
Please help me to get rid of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on line 115 is that your encryption key is just an empty string.

`$key` is empty because two lines up, you have:

```
$USER_PASSWORD_SALT = env('USER_PASSWORD_SALT');
```

The problem there is that `env('USER_PASSWORD_SALT')` is empty so there is no salt.  If you fix that, your function will work.

Comment: @Miron You're welcome. Be sure to upvote and select this answer then. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Run `php artisan key:generate` on your command line (which should located on your Laravel project root) to refresh your application key.

Then clear your cache and sessions and try again.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. It seems to solve that problem, But I can see `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: 2 things, give your cache and session folders permisions (777) then check if you form have a hidden field called "_token"

Comment: there is an input tag with name "_token", and folder permissions are 777, but the same :(